# How to ionize a liquid and apply a force using electrohydrodynamics

Tags: electrochemistry

I would like to create a contactless force on the surface of a liquid by ionizing it and placing the container between a cathode and anode, however I'm not sure how I would go about actually ionizing it.

The liquid is a photopolymer resin, although the specifics of it can be tailored to whatever we need so it makes the question rather broad. So I'm wondering if someone could give me some advice on how to create a surface force on a liquid using electricity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though it is possible to ionize the liquid, it is doubtful you want to do that: the effect of ionization would likely be equivalent to exposing the photopolymer resin to bright light.

[*A System for Cooling Electronic Elements with an EHD Coolant Flow*](https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=imgres&cd=&ved=0ahUKEwisjrWfmf3JAhUKKiYKHcg0CuMQjB0IBjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fiopscience.iop.org%2Farticle%2F10.1088%2F1742-6596%2F494%2F1%2F012010%2Fpdf&psig=AFQjCNF68BikGHpmiAf38eAd9aII7ZAw4w&ust=1451345446315644) from iopscience.iop.org describes setting up and testing a pump using isopropanol as the working fluid.

If you do decide to try electrohydrodynamic pumping, either of an [atomized spray](http://www.ou.edu/mms/class/2011F%20Hydro/Pconanan2paper.pdf) or [EHD pumping of dielectric liquids](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0304388605000616), take precautions against ignition of the liquid and test whether ionization ruins the photoresist.